# How to find the max value of group of arrays

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have six arrays which are of `float` type. Any specific index in all these arrays represent set of values for me. e.g. If index is `0` all the six arrays `0`th index represent a set of values, from which I need to find the max value. Similarly, for all other indexes too.

```
array1  array2  array3  array4  array5  array6    
0       0       0       0       0       0 
1       1       1       1       1       1
```

And so on.

I need to find out which is the max value of a specific index among all these arrays and should store it in another array or list.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Make it more understandable. Adding some code would help.

Comment: I believe you're saying that you're using arrays as a matrix representation and that the "columns" are related ... array1[0], array2[0] and so on and you want to know the maximal value of each column?

Comment: Have you written any code for solving this problem ? If yes.. please paste it and give some more detail. Your problem seems simple, but without a few key details it's not usual to jump directly to the implementation. How do you represent your arrays ? are you sure that the arrays are all of the same size ? if not how do you treat the case when one array is shorter, etc .. are all questions you need an answer to before you start coding.

Comment: By popular demand I did a standard C++ approach. No macros. No assumptions. Fully generic. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190095/how-to-find-the-max-value-of-group-of-arrays/7394944#7394944)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking up the challenge to do this in standard c++, here goes nothing.

I have tried to make the implementation of the algorithm, `reduce_minelement` as generic as possible (not assuming any specific container type or number of value arrays etc.).

I provide several versions, starting with standard c++98 code (which has some kludges, mainly to get the data initialized into STL containers).

### Plain standard C++98

See it live: http://ideone.com/2BlsK

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Containers>
    std::vector<typename Containers::value_type::value_type> 
        reduce_minelement(const Containers& containers)
{
    typedef typename Containers::value_type slice_t;
    typedef typename Containers::const_iterator slice_ci;
    typedef typename slice_t::value_type element_t;
    std::vector<element_t> result;
    result.reserve(containers.size()); // pre-allocated

    for (slice_ci it=containers.begin(); it!=containers.end(); ++it)
    {
        result.push_back(*std::max_element(it->begin(), it->end()));
    }

    return result;
}

typedef int ints_t[6];
static const ints_t s_data[] = { 
    { 19152,     1, 21193, 17574,  8484, 30333 },
    { 20189, 18837, 30734,     2, 22440,  3534 },
        { 3, 26118, 19367, 17877, 24605,  7838 },
    { 30885, 20135,    -4, 31316, 11838,  8926 },
    { 26830, 20209, 27286, 16105, 16601, 28304 },
    { 10208, 28062, 15612, 26270, 19234, 21326 },
     { 5208, 17473,  3383, 15659, 32494, 24231 },
    { 31685, 22500, 18860, 21318, 18893, 21385 },
    { 14295, 17163,  8920, 15986, 13448, 21143 },
    { 20199,  8954,   599, 17459,  3884,  8634 },
    { 16768, 20563,  6727, 26305, 11053,  6418 },
     { 7446,  6853,  5283,  6193, 28291,  4205 },
    { 27056, 17514,  5359, 29656, 10910,  6034 },
    { 21984,  1261,  2404, 17644, 25969,  1735 },
      { 797,  8457, 23584, 29363, 26362, 17383 },
      { 768, 11018, 14991,     0, 28720,  6159 },
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > data;

    for (const ints_t *it=s_data; it!=s_data+(sizeof(s_data)/sizeof(*s_data)); ++it)
        data.push_back(std::vector<int>(*it+0, *it+sizeof(*it)/sizeof(**it)));

    std::vector<int> reduced = reduce_minelement(data);

    std::copy(reduced.begin(), reduced.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));

    return 0;
}
```

### Plain standard C++11

Compile with c++0x support. The benefits are

- much improved initialization
- more flexibility (can be a jagged array now, see demo data)
- legibility (range-based `for` instead of iterator loops), `auto` type deduction
- fewer typedefs to tie things together

**Note** Unfortunately, because codepad.org/ideone.com uses the gcc 4.5.1 compiler, the range-based for is not yet supported; See a slightly modified version live: http://ideone.com/xevL0

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Containers>
    std::vector<typename Containers::value_type::value_type>
         reduce_minelement(const Containers& containers)
{
    std::vector<typename Containers::value_type::value_type> result;
    result.reserve(containers.size()); // pre-allocate

    for (auto& slice: containers)
        result.push_back(*std::max_element(slice.begin(), slice.end()));

    return result;
}

static const std::vector<std::vector<int> > data = { 
       { 52,    1, 93, 74 },
        { 2,   18, 67, 77 },
       { 85,   35, -4     },
       { 48 },
       { 68,   18, 91,  0 },
};

int main()
{
    auto reduced = reduce_minelement(data);
    std::copy(reduced.begin(), reduced.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));

    return 0;
}
```

### C++0x with Boost Range

- More concise code
- allow operating on non-STL containers (like C-style arrays) directly. *This leads to slightly more complicated type deductions in `reduce_minelement`*. Abstraction comes at a cost ;)

**Note** the data (`s_data`) has been omitted because it is identical to the above; you can drop in either one of the `s_data` definitions from the other examples and it would compile and run.

**Note** No online compiler service supports Boost library headers, so you can see this *live* only at home.

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <iterator>

using boost::range_value;
using boost::range_iterator;

template <typename Containers>
    std::vector<typename range_value<typename range_value<Containers>::type>::type> 
         reduce_minelement(const Containers& containers)
{
    std::vector<typename range_value<typename range_value<Containers>::type>::type> result;
    result.reserve(boost::size(containers)); // pre-allocate

    for (auto& slice: containers)
        result.push_back(*boost::max_element(slice));

    return result;
}

typedef int ints_t[6];
static const ints_t s_data[] = { 
    { 19152,     1, 21193, 17574,  8484, 30333 },
    { 20189, 18837, 30734,     2, 22440,  3534 },
        { 3, 26118, 19367, 17877, 24605,  7838 },
    { 30885, 20135,    -4, 31316, 11838,  8926 },
    { 26830, 20209, 27286, 16105, 16601, 28304 },
    { 10208, 28062, 15612, 26270, 19234, 21326 },
     { 5208, 17473,  3383, 15659, 32494, 24231 },
    { 31685, 22500, 18860, 21318, 18893, 21385 },
    { 14295, 17163,  8920, 15986, 13448, 21143 },
    { 20199,  8954,   599, 17459,  3884,  8634 },
    { 16768, 20563,  6727, 26305, 11053,  6418 },
     { 7446,  6853,  5283,  6193, 28291,  4205 },
    { 27056, 17514,  5359, 29656, 10910,  6034 },
    { 21984,  1261,  2404, 17644, 25969,  1735 },
      { 797,  8457, 23584, 29363, 26362, 17383 },
      { 768, 11018, 14991,     0, 28720,  6159 },
};

int main()
{
    boost::copy(reduce_minelement(s_data), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));

    return 0;
}
```

---

## Genericity: what about strings?

All three versions are fully generic towards the type of element. Some other places may need adjustment (like the `ostream_iterator` type) but the actual implementation doesn't mind whether you throw `float`s, `std::string`s, `integers` or, indeed, any comparable type at it.

Demo, based on the last version:

```
typedef std::string elements_t[3];
static const elements_t s_data[] = { 
    { "the", "quick", "fox" },
    { "jumped", "over", "the" },
    { "lazy", "blue", "moon" },
};

int main()
{
    boost::copy(reduce_minelement(s_data), 
       std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> the, the, moon,

### Q.E.D.

Hope this was entertaining for you. It was for me.

Comment: So much thought gone into this I think it deserves an upvote!

Comment: Oops! duh... - replaced min_element with max_element (that was silly of me to miss)